# Creating and using Java Bindings library for PocketSphinxAndroidDemo

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I want to create a Java Bindings library for the [PocketSphinx Android Demo project](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid) for Xamarin, that I can then use in my Android application. I have done the following:

- downloaded the PocketSphinxAndroidDemo project, and installed and run it on my Android device using Eclipse without any issues - the native java code works nicely.
- created a Java Bindings library in Visual Studio with the pocketsphinx-android-0.8-nolib.jar file marked as an EmbeddedJar and marked Copy to output directory always and got this to compile fine. I'm using the jar from the downloaded demo project.
- added an android application project to my Visual Studio solution and added a reference to my bindings library.
- added lib/armeabi/libpocketsphinx_jni.so to my application project (also armeabi-v7a) (using the files from the demo project) and marked the *.so files as AndroidNativeLibrary with Copy to Output directory set to Copy Always.

No matter what I do I can't run the line of C# code

`var config = Decoder.DefaultConfig();`

I always get a `Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception ([as described in my forum post here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15121/java-bindings-library-project-for-pocketsphinx-with-so#latest)). I'm trying to run this line of code because the demo project has this line of java:

`Config config = defaultConfig();`

My question is, do I need to use `DllImport` here? Or perhaps `Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary`? Is this a scenario where the project should be built using ndk-build?

I have tried both DllImport and LoadLibrary with no success. Any leads or things to try much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on from a response that I got in [this forum thread](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/48968/), I worked out that I needed to call

`Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary("pocketsphinx_jni");`

in the OnCreate method of my class, before calling the DefaultConfig method.

Comment: Could you share your binding? I would love to use PocketSphinx with my Xamarin project.

Comment: Hi Florian, No problem, I have posted it as a zip file on my blog here: http://www.web-garden.co.uk/blog/2014/6/2/pocketsphinx-binding-for-xamarin :)

Comment: @DavidConlisk The file is down. Is there anywhere else I can get it? Also, how do I update it to the newest version?

Comment: @amitairos I'm having issues with my site just now, try this link: http://www.web-garden.co.uk/blog/2014/6/2/pocketsphinx-binding-for-xamarin.aspx Unfortunately it's quite old and I'm unsure of how you'd go about updating it. Good luck!

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot!